# how to make this code work with spiffs?

Tags: esp8266, spiffs

So, I have a page to select a txt file from the user's device and save it to SD card:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>File Upload </title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>File Upload </h1>
<form method='POST' action='/upload' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='upload'>
<input type='submit' value='Upload'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my esp8266 code for handling the form :

```cpp
  controlserver.on("/UPL", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(200, "text/html", upl);
  });
 controlserver.on("/upload", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
        request->send(200); }, handleUpload);
        
        
void handleUpload(AsyncWebServerRequest *request, String filename, size_t index, uint8_t *data, size_t len, bool final) {
  String logmessage = "Client:" + request->client()->remoteIP().toString() + " " + request->url();

  if (!index) {
    logmessage = "Upload Start: " + String(filename);
    request->_tempFile = SD.open("/" + filename, "w");
  }

  if (len) {
    request->_tempFile.write(data, len);
    logmessage = "Writing file: " + String(filename) + " index=" + String(index) + " len=" + String(len);
  }

  if (final) {
    logmessage = "Upload Complete: " + String(filename) + ",size: " + String(index + len);
    request->_tempFile.close();
    request->redirect("/");
  }
}
```

My project is not big and it doesn't require SD card, and esp8266 has 4mb memory, I have tried to replace SD with spiffs, but I wasn't successful. I don't know that if it's possible to directly write the txt file to spiffs, but it will be ok if I could save it to a string the write it to a file in spiffs.

Comment: reduce your code to writing `"x"` to spiffs and reading it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/81482/esp-32-upload-files-to-spiffs-via-browser) post, I did solve the problem.

Here is the full code,
My html code for the upload page, the form is in the  tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>File Upload Example</h1>
<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframe"><input type="file" name="upload"><input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<iframe style="visibility: hidden;" src="http://" )+local_IPstr+"/Usm" name="iframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

code for ESP:

```cpp
void handleUpload(AsyncWebServerRequest *request, String filename, size_t index, uint8_t *data, size_t len, bool final){
if (!index) {
    request->_tempFile = SPIFFS.open("/" + filename, "w");
    Serial.println("1");
}
if (len) {
    request->_tempFile.write(data, len);
     Serial.println("2");
}
if (final) {
   Serial.println("3");
    request->_tempFile.close();
    request->redirect("/");
}
}



 controlserver.on("/upload", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
        request->send(200); }, handleUpload);
        


  controlserver.on("/UPL", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(200, "text/html", upl);
  });


  readFile(SPIFFS, "/11.txt"); // show the content of the uploaded file, obviously you should know the name of the uploaded file!
```

you can write a function like this to make sure the file was delivered:

```cpp
  readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
  Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\r\n", path);
  File file = fs.open(path, "r");
  if(!file || file.isDirectory()){
    Serial.println("- empty file or failed to open file");
    return String();
  }
  Serial.println("- read from file:");
  String fileContent;
  while(file.available()){
    fileContent+=String((char)file.read());
  }
  file.close();
  Serial.println(fileContent);

}
```